# WildFly deploy even if hibernate fails to connect to database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Is there a way to force wildfly/jboss to deploy an application even when hibernate fails to build a session factory because it could not connect to the database. Or a way to make wildfly/jboss retry the deployment after a delay?

It makes little sense that an application cannot be deployed without a database connection, yet during runtime recovers from a loss of database connection just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with your idea but never actually tested the behaviour.

Does in your case the application directly ask Hibernate to connect to the database, or is some JDBC connection pool inbetween? I would try to find such resiliency coded in the connection pool rather than the application itself.

Comment: Currently I rely on hibernate to establish the connection though Wildfly given a jndi. In Wildfly there is a Datasource configured with a connection pool.

Comment: Then the question would be whether wildfly can instantiate the connection pool even if at that time the DB is not available. You could remove Hibernate from the picture and have better chances for success. How many connections are configured as minimum? Probably that would have to be a zero.

Comment: Unfortunately removing Hibernate from the application is not possible, is there a method of preventing Hibernate from requiring the connection until WildFly is connected?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to remove Hibernate from your application. But you can strip it off from your problem investigation. One requirement less, more chances of getting support.